# My uitableview cells using in anywhere in application are only selectable on long press ios 9.2, I am not using any gestures

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios9.2

I am using custom xib cells in my application but I am facing a problem regarding all tableviews, `UITableViewCell` is not getting selected on single tap, I have to long press the cell for selecting it. I am using a custom xib cell and I have not used any gesture recognizer in my classes. I am facing this problem in every table view even in `NIDropdownList`’s Tableview Which is an open source library I have previously used many time..

Comment: you getting callback in didSelectRowAtIndexpath ? is this problem only in iOS 9.2 ?

Comment: yeah I am only getting call back when I press and hold a cell for some seconds i am getting this issue only in current application i have checked by creating a test app with table view and that was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using CDSideMenu and TSMessage library which contains UIGestureRecognizers in it.

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(fadeMeOut)];
 [gestureRec setDirection:(self.messagePosition ==TSMessageNotificationPositionTop ? UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp :
UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];

[self addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
[gestureRec setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];

I have set All the gestures to not cancel other touches in view and its solved the problem [gestureRec setCancelsTouchesInView:NO] :)